# Can not input desired number using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am doing task using selenium in C# (NUnit). in my task I have to perform some tasks in "Google Cloud Pricing Calculator" (I have to input 4 in "number of instances field", select N1 series, etc.)

I have tried to find element by its ID but selenium could not find it.
Then I tried "thread.sleep();" function but it did not work either.
After that I tried to use "WebDriverWait" and it did not work either.

[iframe and previous elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAF21.png)

[this is "Number of instances" field, where i tried to find element by ID and css selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV70n.png)

Comment: Is the element inside of the shadow dom, an iframe, frame, or something similar?

Comment: Please share more information so we can help you better

Comment: Please share an image of the element, and it's relevant ancestor elements

Comment: @JoshHeaps 
In HTML I found iframe 

`<iframe src="https://cloud.google.com/frame/products/calculator/index_d6a98ba38837346d20babc06ff2153b68c2990fa24322fe52c5f83ec3a78c6a0.frame" allow="clipboard-write https://cloud-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com" allowfullscreen="" name="goog_333858032"></iframe>`

Comment: Try to make screenshot with more info, like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kvIx.png (Which is a screenshot of: https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/ with the field that this question is about selected )  (O wait, I did do that already for you.... )

Comment: @Luuk everything works perfect on [link](https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/) but i have to work in [link](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this website you have nested iframes. You'll need to step into the first Iframe, and then into the second.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(By.XPath("//devsite-iframe/iframe"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(By.XPath("//iframe[@id='myFrame']"));
// Your code here
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

This will step into the iframes that hold the number of instances, then step all the way back out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to locate an iFrame object which is the **closest parent** of the element you are trying to find and assign it to a variable: `var iframe = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe"))`

Then, you need to switch to the iframe: `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframe);`

As soon as you switched, you can search for the "number of instances field" element.

Iframe is a part of "hidden DOM" which isn't directly accessible by Selenium, unless you switch a focus on it.

Comment: IFrames are not part of a shadow dom. Shadow doms are found within a `#shadow-root`.

Comment: @JoshHeaps thanks! I was trying to explain that iframes are separate from the main DOM and are hidden from Selenium unless switched to. I'll correct my explanation.